# Loop through .csv files with conditions in different columns

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary

I've got a large .csv file with this format:

*"String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6", etc*

I am interested in extracting information from a column as long as it is linked to the following one.

To give a more clear example, suppose columns number 3 and 4 are formed by teams, and they represent whom they host (col 3 is the local team).

*"First", "Result", "Philadelphia", "Miami", etc

"Second", "Result", "Dallas", "Cleveland", etc

"Third", "Result", "Miami", "Cleveland", etc

"Fourth", "Result", "Cleveland", "Miami", etc

"Fifth", "Result", "Dallas", "Philadelphia", etc

"Sixth", "Result", "Cleveland", "Dallas", etc

"Seventh", "Result", "Miami", "Philadelphia", etc

"Eighth", "Result", "Philadelphia", "Miami", etc

"Ninth", "Result", "Cleveland", "Miami", etc*

And I want to obtain a list consisting of the teams they host, without repetition

```
Cleveland hosts
Dallas
Miami

Dallas hosts
Cleveland
Philadelphia

Miami hosts
Cleveland
Philadelphia

Philadelphia hosts
Miami
```

After that, I'd like to write in a file all rows concerning both patterns, this is, if I wanted to see matches between Cleveland and Miami I would like to have a .csv like this,

*"Third", "Result", "Miami", "Cleveland", etc

"Fourth", "Result", "Cleveland", "Miami", etc

"Ninth", "Result", "Cleveland", "Miami", etc*

With the following code, I manage to read one column and store all unique elements in a dictionary so that I can choose a word from there later. I could do the same with column number 4 and repeating the code by changing the value of the parameter Wanted_Column to 3

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict, OrderedDict

Var = 1 
Wanted_Column = 2 # Col I want to analyze 

with open('file.csv', "rb") as inputfile:
    data = csv.reader(inputfile)
    seen = defaultdict(set)

    countd = Counter(
        row[Wanted_Column]
        for row in data
        if row[Wanted_Column] and row[Wanted_Column] not in seen[row[Var]] and not seen[row[Var]].add(row[Wanted_Column])
    )

y = OrderedDict(sorted(countd.items(), key = lambda t: t[0]))

for line in y:
    print line
```

The result is,

```
Cleveland
Dallas
Miami 
Philadelphia
```

So, my question is, what should I add to have a double condition and show elements the way I have exposed?

After that, to write rows in another file I've got this code,

```
look_for = set([ELEMENT IN DICTIONARY])

with open('file.csv','rb') as inf, open('output_file.csv','wb') as outf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')

    outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if row[Wanted_column] in look_for)
```

And with just one element it works well, but of course, as the previous condition is not well defined, I don't know what should I change to get the result that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of sets to keep track of the hosting teams and the unique visiting teams.  Here's an example.

```
import csv

# load the csv file
rows = [r for r in csv.reader(file('sample.csv','r'))]

# order preservation list
preserve_order = []

# track the schedule from the hosting team's point of view
hosting_teams = {}

# change the wanted column here
wanted_column = 3

for row in rows:
    # strip out the double quotes
    row = [c.replace('"','') for c in row] 

    the_host = row[2]
    the_order = row[0]

    preserve_order.append(the_order)

    # create a dictionary with a unique set of visiting teams
    host_schedule = hosting_teams.setdefault(the_host,set([]))

    # add the team visit
    visiting_team = row[wanted_column]
    host_schedule.add((visiting_team,the_order))



output = []
for hosting_team,host_schedule in hosting_teams.items():
    for visiting_team,the_order in host_schedule:
        output.append([the_order,"Result",hosting_team,visiting_team])    

output.sort(key=lambda x:preserve_order.index(x[0]))

csv.writer(file('output.csv','wb')).writerows(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is that if I do this the .csv is global (all matches'd appear) and sorted randomly, this is, game 9 can appear before game 4 despite both have been played at Clevland and Miami's been the receiving team, and I will also see matches played by Philadelphia and Dallas. If I'm not wrong, your code will write a .csv with all rows gathered by the 2nd column. It works, but it doesn't really solve my problem.
Firstly, how could I use the OrderedDict with two arguments sorted by the 1st of them, and 2ndly, how would I write only one of the 'double patterns' to the .csv?

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use a dictionary of sets?

```
 f = open('test.csv')
hosts = {}

#read
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('"', '')
    res = line.split(',')

    if not hosts.get(res[2]):
        hosts[res[2]] = set([])

    hosts.get(res[2]).add(res[3])

#print
for key in sorted(hosts.keys()):
    print 'HOST', key
    for guest in sorted(list(hosts[key])):
        print 'GUEST', guest

print hosts
```

Then the final print would just be looping through the `hosts` keys and printing the contents of the set.

And if the number of columns isn't known up front but you know it goes `host, guest` then its just a matter of having an inner loop that traverses the whole line starting from position 2.

added the last line to show sorted printing. The only difference between the inputs in this script and yours is I removed the `.etc` column and assume that the input stops there. Extending this should be trivial

Comment: Thank you. Actually I hadn't thought about that, I'll have a look at it. From my last piece of code, the writing part, what would I need to change in the last line?

Comment: look at the example above. It does the sorted printed for you too. Just modify your script to follow the patterns in mine.

Comment: just change the `print` statements to file writes with your formatting rules